# Image not staying in table container

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image][not in container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK8XM.jpg)

I am trying to get the picture to stay into the left column but it doesn't seem to stay. As you can see, it hovers over the table. What can I do to make it stay within the table?

```html
<table align="center" style="width:550px" id="table" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align: left" rowspan="2">
      <img src="avi.png" alt="" id="avatar" />
    </th>
    <th style="text-align: left">
      <h1 id="hello">My Resume</h1>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left">
      <p>Hello this is a crazy little test that i am doing to see if this code works</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you want to image override text ??

Comment: I want something like this: http://seanhalpin.io/

Comment: If you look in the middle of the page where it says "What can I do" you can see that he has a picture on the left and thext on the right, then under that he has it reversed. I want to do that but when I do it, my picture keeps overlapping the text rather that being next to it like the example

Comment: i update my answer. check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specifically want something like the example you gave, using tables is the old clunky way of doing it. I'd suggest using flexbox, it's a simple way of lining things up and making them look nice.

Here is an example:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.resume {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.resume-picture {
  border: 10px solid #1976D2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f3f2f1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  height: 175px;
}
.resume-content {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.resume-content h2 {
  color: #1976D2;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.resume-content p {
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="resume">
  <img class="resume-picture" src="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/3534427?v=3" />
  <div class="resume-content">
    <h2>My Resume</h2>
    <p>Hello this is a crazy little test that i am doing to see if this code works.
      <br>Hello this is a crazy little test that i am doing to see if this code works.
      <br>Hello this is a crazy little test that i am doing to see if this code works.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this is the sort of thing you are looking for.

Comment: That excatly what I wanted! Thank you. You are a life saver. Last quick question. There seems to be a big gap between the text and the picture and I want it to come closer together so that it is ore centered like the example. How would I do that?

Comment: There shouldn't be a gap, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using google chrome. How can I attach a picture on the comment so that Incan show you a screen shot?

Comment: @MichaelGiron if you upload it to a site like https://postimage.org/ then you can post the image link in the comments

Comment: Okay. sweet. Thanks for letting me know. This is the picture for what I'm getting: https://postimg.org/image/hs367mvjd/

Comment: So, i finally figured it out. It seemed to be doing that because I in my CSS file I put an img selector and it was messing with the code you gave me. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Override image on text**

```html
<table align="center" style="width:550px;border:1px solid #c2c2c2;    position: relative;" id="table" cellpadding="5" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align: left;border-right:1px solid #c2c2c2;min-width:50px;" rowspan="2">
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/user.png" alt="" id="avatar" width="100" height="100" style="
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 14px;
        top: 33px;
        z-index: 2;
        opacity: 0.5;" />
    </th>
    <th style="text-align: left;border-bottom:1px solid #c2c2c2;">
      <h1 id="hello">My Resume</h1>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left">
      <p>Hello this is a crazy little test that i am doing to see if this code works</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**image in table container** update style

```html
<table align="center" style="width:550px;border:1px solid #c2c2c2;" id="table" cellpadding="5" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align: left;border-right:1px solid #c2c2c2;" rowspan="2">
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/user.png" alt="" id="avatar" width="100" height="100" />
    </th>
    <th style="text-align: left;border-bottom:1px solid #c2c2c2;">
      <h1 id="hello">My Resume</h1>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left">
      <p>Hello this is a crazy little test that i am doing to see if this code works</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```